# Angular >2 Dynamic object key causing template parse error

Tags: angular, angular2-template, computed-properties, event-binding

When trying to place a value for a key, with a variable inside of my event binding expression, I am given a template parse error: `Parser Error: Unexpected token [, expected identifier, keyword, or string at column...` [image: error img]
my expression is:
`(ngModelChange)="action.emit({type: 'CACHE_SELECTED_COMPANY', payload: { [selectedCompany.id]:{selected: true, details: false}}})"`

I thought that providing a variable name for a key in [square brackets] was allowed, and my question is, should I be able to provide a variable as a key in an Angular 2 template's, event binding expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computed properties are currently [not supported in templates](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13855).

Template may be refactored to not use computed properties:

```
(ngModelChange)="action.emit({type: 'CACHE_SELECTED_COMPANY', payload: getPayload(selectedCompany.id})"
```

Or entire `action.emit(...)` may be moved to model change callback.

Comment: Thank you, that dispelled my confusion! :)